# copy not picking up correct source folder

Tags: windows, powershell, copy

I have this script

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path \\exp-01\Uploads |
          Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -Last 1
```

The folder variable is correctly set up, when I check it, it comes up as

```
    Directory: \\exp-01\Uploads


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        29/05/2017     08:17            149604223125762
```

But when I do this

```
copy $folder E:\InvoiceUploads\files\ -Recurse
```

I get an error,

> copy : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\web.developer.03\149604223125762' because it does not exist.

The PowerShell is running the folder (the prompt is):

```
C:\Users\web.developer.03>
```

So, basically it it not picking up correct source, instead it is taking up the current directory as the source. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$folder` contains a `DirectoryInfo` object, not a path. By default PowerShell expands the `Name` property of these objects, so `Copy-Item` is looking for the folder name in the current working directory.

Either expand the `FullName` property when selecting the folder:

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path \\exp-01\Uploads |
          Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -Last 1 -Expand FullName
```

or use the `FullName` property in the `Copy-Item` statement:

```
copy $folder.FullName E:\InvoiceUploads\files\ -Recurse
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you're using the MS CMD syntax.
(Notice you're using Copy - not Copy-Item)

Did you try and use Powershells cmdlet for copying, along with named parameters for source and destination? Perhaps it helps you.

```
SYNTAX
    Copy-Item [-Path] <String[]> [[-Destination] <String>] [-Container] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-Exclude <String[
    ]>] [-Filter <String>] [-Force] [-Include <String[]>] [-PassThru] [-Recurse] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [-UseTransaction
    [<SwitchParameter>]] [<CommonParameters>]

    Copy-Item [[-Destination] <String>] [-Container] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-Exclude <String[]>] [-Filter <Strin
    g>] [-Force] [-Include <String[]>] [-PassThru] [-Recurse] -LiteralPath <String[]> [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [-UseTransac
    tion [<SwitchParameter>]] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: `copy` is an alias for `Copy-Item`. His syntax is perfectly correct. The issue is with how PowerShell handles the value of `$folder`.